# Clear Facebook post to feed image cached

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I updated old image to new image (same old image_url). 
Then when i click postTofeed button, should show updated image... But feed image does not change. 
I tried using [Debugger Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), but not solved yet..(of course in debugger tool page,  feed image changed into new image)
How to clear cached image?

Here my feed code

```
function postToFeed {
    var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'url',
        picture: 'image_url',
        name: 'name',
        caption: 'caption',
        description: 'description'
    };

    function callback(response) {
        if (response) {
            procShare('<?=$it_id?>', 'facebook', response['post_id']);
        }
    }
    FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
picture: 'image_url',
```

to

```
picture: 'image_url?some_random_text=12345',
```

That's all you need to do. If you need to change images again a lot and you want it to always update to a new image you update, try

```
picture: 'image_url?r='Math.random(),
```

The concept is just add some change to url so that it's not the same to prevent cache.

Comment: The 'picture' parameter is now deprecated; any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

first, i solve this problem temporailly.

1.Image file name in server change into tmp name.
2.In url included function of 'feed to post', excute the function. (this show no image, because code has before changing file name.)
3.Image file name change into origin name.
4.that's it! you can show new image for same url and same image file name.